# Python asyncio not executing

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm not really a Python expert, so excuse me if this is really obvious. I'm trying to run a script using asyncio. Relevant bits of code:

```
import websockets
import asyncio

stream = websockets.connect(<resource_uri>)

async def main():
    async with stream as receiver:
        while True:
            data = receiver.recv()
            # do stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When I run this, I get:

DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

Similarly, using

'''
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
'''

instead, I get

RuntimeError: no running event loop.

Any ideas? I guess it's something to do with main() not running in the correct thread...

I'm using Python 3.10.

Comment: The deprecation warning is a new "fearure" in 3.10, read here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop

Answer (score 2):

Newer code should use just `asyncio.run(main())` - that will automatically create a new instance loop and "run until complete" on the awaitable.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies! I'm now getting: RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<main() running at  <remoed_path>/main.py:22> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at>/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:184]> got Future <Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py:384]> attached to a different loop

Comment: The answer is correct IMO. There must be another issue responsible for the `RuntimeError`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there must be.

Comment: Issue probably is, once you call asyncio.run(main()) once, you've started an event loop that doesn't _necessarily_ (in my experience) go away with a fresh execution. Maybe that is a result of my environment being crap or something.

Therefore (as I often experienced) that second execution is looking to start a further run of main() in a further loop, hence the warning.

Comment: Hmmmm. Just reading up and the newer methods _should_ clean up after themselves. 

Is the class/.py "stream" something forked off "Streams"?

Comment: It's from a call to websockets.connect(..). I'll update my post...

Answer (score 1):

Try this, works for me on 3.8 (and probably originally got from someone smarter than me that posted it on here!!)

```
 try:
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
 except RuntimeError:  # 'RuntimeError: There is no current event loop...'
    loop = None

 if loop and loop.is_running():
     print('Async event loop already running. Adding coroutine to the event loop.')
     tsk = loop.create_task(main())
     # ^-- https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-object
     # Optionally, a callback function can be executed when the coroutine completes
     tsk.add_done_callback(
        lambda t: print(f'Task done with result = {t.result()}'))
 else:
    print('Starting new event loop')
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: As you wrote this is copied from somewhere and it addresses a different issue than it was asked.

Comment: So in your opinion it doesn't (i) detect (and handle) when there actually is "no running event loop" and (ii) doesn't start a event new loop if there is "no running event loop"? That is an interesting take on addressing a different issue than was asked.

Comment: If you are are starting the event loop as the first thing after the program start, then you don't need to test wether it isn't running already.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I try that, I frequently get told there is an event loop already running. Whether windows isn't cleaning itself up right or not I don't know. Either way, I need the above to run what I want to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's an issue with websockets and Python 3.10. Looks like I'll have to find a workaround. Thanks for your time!